# cakephp route to not allow file extension

Tags: regex, cakephp, routes, cakephp-1.3

I need a cakephp route which will catch all urls if not matched in previous routes that do not contain file extensions.

Current route for catch all below

```
Router::connect('/*', array('controller' => 'frontend', 'action' => 'display',null));
```

I need the above route modified to not all urls with file extensions to be caught

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I have donr in my app based on CakePHP 1.2 to add extension to dynamic generated images is as follows:

```
Router::connect('/postImage/*', array('controller' => 'posts','action' => 'postImage', 'url' => array('ext' => 'png')));
```

The above code makes both the folloing url are accesible:
http://myhost.com/posts/postImage/125
and
http://myhost.com/posts/postImage/125.png

I think that the same will going with CakePHP 1.3 and I hope that It helps you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand very well your demand, but you can do this:

```
Router::parseExtensions('html');
Router::connect('/*/:title', array('controller' => 'frontend', 'action' => 'display',null), 
              array(
        'pass' => array('title')
      )
);
```

And the link:

```
$html->link('Title', array('controller' => 'frontend', 'action' => 'display', 'title' => Inflector::slug('text to slug', '-'), 'ext' => 'html'))
```

I hope this will help you. good luck